# Incluir funciones de scroll hechas en Javascript en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Buen día, intento agregar un archivo Javascript a un proyecto de Angular.
Tengo un archivo llamado `scroll.js` el cual tiene una función para cuando se haga scroll en la página, vayan apareciendo los elementos conforme vaya bajando el scroll. Hice las pruebas en una página con HTML y CSS y funciona perfectamente.

Este es mi código en Javascript (`scroll.js`).

```
let animado = document.querySelectorAll(".animated");

function mostrarScroll() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    for (var i = 0; i < animado.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(animado);
        var alturaAnimado = animado[i].offsetTop;
        if(alturaAnimado - 500 < scrollTop)
        {
            animado[i].style.opacity = 1;
            animado[i].classList.add("fadeInLeft");
        }
    }
}
    
window.addEventListener('scroll', mostrarScroll);
```

En Angular he intentado importarlo en `angular.json` en la parte de scripts:

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "src/scroll.js"
 ]
```

Y también en el componente donde se aplicará esa función:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import "../../../assets/js/scroll";
```

Y ninguna de estas dos formas logro hacer que me funcione el scroll. Cabe mencionar que agregué un `console.log` en `scroll.js` para ver si Angular estaba reconociendo el `.js` y si me muestra el mensaje en la consola.

Mi pregunta es
¿Estoy haciendo mal la importación del Javascript? O, ¿necesito realizar algo más?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perri intenta asi, en angular.json tenes que tener en la prop scripts:["path a myScript.js"] , luego encapsula tu script de js en una función:

```
let myScript = function(){
  console.log("hola desde myScript ;)");
  let animado = document.querySelectorAll(".animated");

  function mostrarScroll() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    for (var i = 0; i < animado.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(animado);
        var alturaAnimado = animado[i].offsetTop;
        if(alturaAnimado - 500 < scrollTop)
        {
            animado[i].style.opacity = 1;
            animado[i].classList.add("fadeInLeft");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

luego en el component vas a crear un declare var para hacer referencia a la lib que incluiste :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var myScript: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  instanceLib: any;
  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("hola");
    this.instanceLib = myScript();
    this.instanceLib.mostrarScroll(); 
  }

}
```

en el OnInit, creas una instancia de la funcion y listo!

Comment: Estuve revisando tu respuesta, y en el `onInit()` me da un error cuando quiero acceder a la función `mostrarScroll()`, lo demás si me funciona bien, si me muestra los `console.log`, solo me da error en esa parte de acceder a la función `mostrarScroll()`

Comment: _myScript_ debería tener un `return { mostrarScroll: mostrarScroll }`

Comment: @Triby faltaba ese return, muchas gracias :D

Comment: @altoqueperro También agregué esta linea `window.addEventListener('scroll', mostrarScroll);` antes del `return { mostrarScroll: mostrarScroll }` y con eso ya me funcionó las animaciones al hacer scroll. En verdad, muchas gracias :D